# How to detect which item will be snapped to, when swiping in FlatList that snaps to interval?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have a component with a horizontal `<FlatList>` that contains 100s of items (calendar days), with the same width as the screen. The `<FlatList>` is set to snap to an interval similar to the screen width, so I can swipe between items.

When I swipe to a specific date, I want to update the UI to show that date, above the `<FlatList>`. Right now I'm using `onMomentumScrollEnd` to find the final offset and the day item to show in the header.

However, the user experience is not optimal, since the header is not updated before the swiping/scrolling animation ends.

What I need is is a way to determine which offset that the `<FlatList>` will snap to, as soon as the user swipes.

I guess `onScroll` could be useful, but I'm a little lost on finding the next offset hat the `<FlatList>` will snap to, based on the event I get from `onScroll`.

However, I can see that some 3rd party modules like `react-native-snap-carousel` is doing this, using `onScroll`, so I guess it's possible.

I have chosen not to use `react-native-snap-carousel` as it really decreases the swiping animation performance on my screen. And looking into the code if the modul gives no clear answer, since this module has tons of features that I don't need, which are part of the code that it uses to determine the next `snapTo` offSet

Answer (score 6):

To detect "snap" in FlatList, you can use **viewabilityConfig** and **onViewableItemsChanged** Flatlist properties.

See code (for **Class** and **Hooks** Components) below where I handle "snap" in **onViewChanged** method:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, FlatList, View} from 'react-native';

// CLASS COMPONENT API
export class DemoViewabilityConfigClass extends React.Component {
  flatlistRef;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0,
    };
  }

  onViewChanged = ({viewableItems, index}) => {
    console.log('I snapped to', viewableItems);
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
      const {item: activeItem, index: activeIndex} = viewableItems[0];
      console.log(activeItem, activeIndex);
      this.setState({activeIndex: activeIndex});
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        ref={ref => (this.flatlistRef = ref)}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          marginHorizontal: 10,
        }}
        snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width}
        decelerationRate={0}
        overScrollMode={'never'}
        snapToAlignment={'center'}
        data={[
          {
            id: 'something',
            other: 'data',
          },
          {
            id: 'else',
            other: 'data',
          },
        ]}
        onScrollEndDrag={() => console.log('Scroll end')}
        horizontal={true}
        viewabilityConfig={{itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 70}}
        onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewChanged}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
          console.log('Scroll failed', info);
          const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
          wait.then(() => {
            this.flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
              index: info.index,
              animated: true,
            });
          });
        }}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                marginRight: 20,
                height: 20,
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 20,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

// HOOKS API
export function DemoViewabilityConfigHooks() {
  const flatlistRef = useRef(null);
  const [activeEventIndex, setActiveEventIndex] = useState(0);

  const onViewChanged = React.useRef(({viewableItems}) => {
    console.log('Items ', viewableItems);
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
      const {index, item} = viewableItems[0];
      console.log('Active index', index);
      setActiveEventIndex(index);
    }
  });

  const viewConfigRef = React.useRef({viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50});

  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={flatlistRef}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        marginHorizontal: 10,
      }}
      snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width}
      decelerationRate={0}
      overScrollMode={'never'}
      snapToAlignment={'center'}
      data={[
        {
          id: 'something',
          other: 'data',
        },
        {
          id: 'else',
          other: 'data',
        },
      ]}
      onScrollEndDrag={() => console.log('Scroll end')}
      horizontal={true}
      viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
      onViewableItemsChanged={onViewChanged.current}
      onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
        console.log('Scroll failed', info);
        const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        wait.then(() => {
          flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
            index: info.index,
            animated: true,
          });
        });
      }}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              marginRight: 20,
              height: 20,
              width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 20,
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

If you e.g. need to change component state inside onViewChanged method, you **need to wrap these 2 props into Ref() when using Functional components** / Hooks API.
Otherwise, it results in "*Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported.*" **error** .
Also, you need to pass these props to Flalist by using **.current** syntax.

Here is GIF example:

[image]

Comment: And, just btw,  they improved performance a lot in "react-native-snap-carousel": "4.0.0-beta.6" - but I am not sure if it's already merged in master or not).